# How to set tm values "Weekly" or "Monthly" without breaking limits

Tags: c++

Basically what I'm trying to do is allow users to set a Weekly or Monthly event and creating and scheduling more tm values based on user input. For example, say you want to schedule a weekly Gym session starting today at 4:00 PM. You want to two this for three weeks. It would schedule as follows:

Gym Week 1 4/12/2019 4:00 PM

Gym Week 2 4/19/2019 4:00 PM

Gym Week 3 4/26/2019 4:00 PM

Or if you did it monthly, it would look like this:

Gym Month 1 4/12/2019 4:00 PM

Gym Month 2 5/12/2019 4:00 PM

Gym Month 3 6/12/2019 4:00 PM

As it stands, I can currently do this. However, what I'm having a problem with is when the user sets a date past the current limit. For example, say you wanted to schedule for FOUR weeks, it should look like this:

Gym Week 1 4/12/2019 4:00 PM

Gym Week 2 4/19/2019 4:00 PM

Gym Week 3 4/26/2019 4:00 PM

Gym Week 4 5/3/2019 4:00 PM

Instead, when I try to move past 4/30/2019, I get this error

```
__crt_time_is_day_valid(tm_value->tm_year, tm_value->tm_mon, tm_value->tm_mday)
```

I'm guessing this means that instead of setting the date as 5/3, it's setting it as 4/33, which is invalid.

This is how I'm going about adding the dates:

Weekly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumDates; i++) {
    tempevent = event;
    temptime = settime;
    tempevent += " Week ";
    tempevent += to_string(i + 1);
    temptime.tm_mday += (7 * i);
    addDate(tempevent, temptime);
}
```

Monthly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumDates; i++) {
    tempevent = event;
    temptime = settime;
    tempevent += " Month ";
    tempevent += to_string(i + 1);
    temptime.tm_mon += i;
    addDate(tempevent, temptime);
}
```

Is there a way I could have dates added over the current month/year spill over into the next, rather than adding an invalid date?

Answer (score 0):

OK I actually found a solution on my own. I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but it works.

```
time_t newtime;
std::time_t tt = system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now());
tm curtime = *localtime(&tt);
for (int i = 0; i < NumDates; i++) {
    tempevent = event;
    temptime = settime;
    temptime.tm_isdst = curtime.tm_isdst;
    tempevent += " Week ";
    tempevent += to_string(i + 1);
    temptime.tm_mday += (7 * i);
    time_t newtemp = mktime(&temptime);
    temptime = *localtime(&newtemp);
    addDate(tempevent, temptime);
}
```

Perhaps a little convoluted, but basically changing tm to time_t fixes the problem. After that, I change it back to a tm value. However, mktime has an issue where the hour is often off by 1. From my understanding, this is due to mktime guessing whether it's daylight savings or not. So I set the daylight saving's time to the current daylight savings time.

My only worry is that if the user schedules something after a daylight saving's shift, there might be a problem...I'm hoping that's not the case, but for now this solves the current problem.